# Are there any other Force users remaining in the galaxy by the time of RotJ?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

It has been repeatedly asserted by official sources that as of Yoda's passing, Luke is the last Jedi in the galaxy. Of course, in accordance to the Rule of Two, Darth Sidious and Darth Vader are the only Sith in the galaxy, and upon Anakin's redemption, the last.

Besides the three mentioned above, are there any other Force users in the known galaxy at that point in time? Of all the known Force users dating to the Imperial era:

> All known Inquisitors have been slain by the end of Rebels Season 2. Is the Inquisitorius still operational? We also have Kanan and Ezra who consider themselves full-fledged Jedi, so with Luke confirmed as the last living Jedi in RotJ the future seems ominous for these two. Maul is not a Sith any longer but he has been slain by Obi-Wan in Rebels Season 3. The witches of Dathomir seem to have been fully exterminated during the Clone Wars and what spirits remained in the mortal realm have been dissipated in Rebels Season 3 as well. The only true unknown at this point is Ahsoka, who seems to have likely survived the fight with Vader as hinted by some official source(s). She does not consider herself to be a Jedi any longer, so the Luke-is-the-last-Jedi issue would not affect her.

So barring the last example, are there any other Force users alive by the time of the Battle of Endor? "Supernatural" beings like the Bendu or the Whills, and Force-sensitives who have not yet learnt to actively utilise their affinity with the Force (e.g. babies) do not qualify. I'm only looking for examples of people who know they are Force-sensitive and have learnt to control it and use it at will. It can either be named individuals or unnamed entities (individuals or groups) whose existence are confirmed nonetheless.

Comment: [Abeloth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Abeloth) died in 44 ABY, and she was probably the strongest force entity ever to exist. But then I have no idea what level or sublevel of canon she counts as this week…

Comment: Define "Force user". Specifically a Jedi, someone _trained_ to use the Force (even if another faction trained them), anyone who _uses_ the Force knowingly (even if untrained), or anyone who uses the Force unknowingly (e.g. the theory that Anakin's engineering genius stems from him unknowingly using the Force when he really wants to make something work)?

Comment: @Flater I already defined the context. Read the last paragraph

Answer (score 1):

**It is very unlikely there are strong & trained Force users except Palpatine, Luke and Vader**. Who and what is Snoke remains to be seen, but I doubt he was a major player in time of RotJ. Of course, that could be reconed (and ruin the story).

Certainly there are people who are Force sensitive (Leia is one example), but their powers are relatively weak and raw. Even Luke's formal training didn't last long. There are no **institutionalized trainers** like in previous times (Jedi Temple, Sith Academy, Nightsisters, Guardians of the Whills ...) or at least they do not appear in story. I doubt powerful Force-wielding organization could remain in shadows and not make any impact on the Galaxy in such long time during original trilogy and before that in Age of Empire .

As for Ahsoka, Kanan and Ezra, we could only speculate. But I doubt they could survive until Battle of Hoth. Remember, they were all part of the Rebellion, so was Luke, they all know about Force, and yet Luke (well-known figure in Rebellion circles, man who destroyed Death Star) remained unaware of their existence and completely untrained. Not to mention three of them were known to Palpatine & Vader who would certainly look for them. But, as I said, this is all just a speculation.

Comment: Snoke may or may not be a major player at the time (if he turns out to be Plagueis, as many people speculate, then he would be). But he is certainly a strong Force-sensitive, and appears to be old enough to have been alive during RotJ, and likely well aware of his Force abilities by then

Comment: @RemyLebeau I doubt powerful darksider would remain idle for so long, never appearing on galactic scene for decades. Plageuis theory is dead for all practical purposes, because it was confirmed that Sidious killed him, and there is no comeback for Sith. Beside, this would ruin Chosen One prophecy about destruction of Sith Order. Snoke was probably just a minor player (possibly kid) during events of RotJ.

Comment: I wouldn't count Snoke because my question was asking about Force users active within the known galaxy during the Imperial period and Snoke was located in the Unknown Regions. You know, unknown? lol. In any case, the First Order found Snoke there. Who knows, maybe this is one of those digged too deep and awakened an ancient evil kind of story.

Comment: @thegreatjedi It is entirely possible they are going to pull deus ex machina on Snoke, from Unknown Regions, dormant evil or even another galaxy. Second possibility, Palpatine's secret apprentice or something like that. Any way, there is no way of making him active during original trilogy without ruining the story.